# What is the best color space for motion detection

Tags: emgucv

I am using Emgu with C#.

I have a stream of jepgs coming from a camera feed.  At the moment I use the absdiff between the 2 images to get the motion changes.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> _diffBetweenCurrentAndPrevious = _currentFrame.Convert<Bgr, Byte>().AbsDiff(PreviousFrame.Convert<Bgr, Byte>());
```

I then enumerate through the data array of the image holding all the changes and  look for motion above a certain threshold.

```
 float diffCouner = 0;
 for (int y = 0; y < 576; y++)
 {
    for (int x = 0; x < 720; x++)
    {
       if (_diffBetweenCurrentAndPrevious.Data[y, x, 0] >= 10
        || _diffBetweenCurrentAndPrevious.Data[y, x, 1] >= 10 ||
         _diffBetweenCurrentAndPrevious.Data[y, x, 2] >= 10)
         {
            BaseImage.Data[y, x, 0] = _currentFrame.Data[y, x, 0];
            BaseImage.Data[y, x, 1] = _currentFrame.Data[y, x, 1];
            BaseImage.Data[y, x, 2] = _currentFrame.Data[y, x, 2];
            diffCouner++;
          }
      }
  }
```

At the moment I am using BGR.

Is it better to use HSV or YCC or..?

I had noticed that I had to use a lower threshold when using YCC because the motion did not seem clear for a car passing by at night.

I am interested in the best approach.

Or should I use `<Gray,Byte>` format?

The reason I am asking is that I have tried them all and them all seem to work.  But it may not be so good during different times of the day, for instant a dull or bright day.  Or a low contrast.

I could and will run tests over several days but I will be like a Red Indian praying for the seasons to change.

Any advice would be welcome.

Thanks

Just in case any one is following my question with interest I have found that using the `<Gray,Byte>` does not give good enough results for light changes.

I am now running the tests with `<HSV,Byte>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to had exactly the same problems. I dont think  there is any way to solve your problem. I offer you to create an app were you can  change your h s v parameters on run time and checking from threshold if your combination is good enough. I used this project for that . I hope it will help http://www.osslab.com.tw/@api/deki/files/3550/=An_autonomous%252c_co-operative_telerobotic_agent_framework_for_WowWee_Rovio_-_Konstantinos_Tsimpoukas_1130191.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you for color tracking to choose an appropriate space color
as rbg space is not very
good it's too sensitive even to small illumination variance.
It really depends on the objects you want to track and tracking scenario,
all my best

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thoughts and comments it is much appreciated.  I am not doing tracking at this time.  But if I was I would probably use the Hue + Sat channels to do so :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a greater level of sensitivity, try the following (both foreground and background images are in BGR format):

```
int diff0 = Math.Abs(image0.Data[j, i, 0] - image1.Data[j, i, 0]);
int diff1 = Math.Abs(image0.Data[j, i, 1] - image1.Data[j, i, 1]);
int diff2 = Math.Abs(image0.Data[j, i, 2] - image1.Data[j, i, 2]);
int diff = Math.Max(diff0, diff1);
diff = Math.Max(diff, diff2);
```

the resulting value "diff" is the biggest difference of the 3 channels. This approach has always worked well for my various background subtraction needs.